# Word 2007: Table of Contents dialogue box does not appear

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, macros, table-of-contents

According to the Microsoft Office 2007 training and locations elsewhere on the Microsoft help forum, if a user of Microsoft Office Word 2007 selects References->Table of Contents ->Insert Table of Contents then the Table of Contents dialogue box should appear, allowing for specification of included headings and other configurations.

I found this to be true a few days ago when I was working on documents using my copy of Microsoft Office Word 2007. However, currently when I follow these steps the dialogue does not appear.  Is there a way to figure out what may be causing this issue, and/or correct it? I was experimenting with writing macros earlier, so I do not know if somehow I altered the default template or building blocks in some way, but I do not beleive I did anything that should have that affect.

I have tried renaming the Microsoft Building Blocks file located at `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033` and allowing it to regenerate a new copy, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: please consider adding the answer provided by the link to SU as an answer to your question. adding links as plain answers is desencouraged.

Comment: I did as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had a macro sub named InsertTableOfContents which was intercepting the command. 
Stefan Blom provided the following solution through the Microsoft User's Forum:

> See if you inadvertently added a macro sub called InsertTableOfContents, which would intercept the command to display the TOC dialog box. Delete the macro if you find it.

Also see solution provided on the forum [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/word-2007-table-of-contents-dialogue-box-does-not/4f679d28-e7db-4970-9be0-05a24a8be88e?tab=allreplies#tabs).

I opted to simply rename the macro in my case, which resolved the issue.